# NextRequest client ip and geo city fails in Google Cloud Run

Tags: next.js, serverless

I am using Nextjs in my project
I want to use NextRequest in a Middleware to obtain client ip and geo.city
Next Documentation says "This information is provided by your hosting platform"

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/next-server#nextrequest

When I deploy my project to Google Cloud Run, I get undefined client ip and geo.city

My project works when I deploy it in Vercel.
But it doesn't work when I deploy in Google Cloud Run

Do I have to use some special configuration in google Cloud Run to fix it?